# Serving Multiple WSGI Applications As Different Virtual Hosts on Apache

Tags: django, apache, virtualenv, mod-wsgi, wsgi

I have an EC2 AWS server on which I would like to host a couple of Django applications. Each of these apps has its own URL. For instance,

`example1.com`
`example2.com`

By itself, `example1.com` works. The problem is getting `example2.com` to work with it at the same time.

When I visit `example2.com`, I get an error:

```
DisallowedHost at /
Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'example2.com'. You may need to add 'example2.com' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://example2.com
Django Version: 1.9.13
Exception Type: DisallowedHost
Exception Value:    
Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'example2.com'. You may need to add 'example2.com' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
Exception Location: /var/www/vhosts/example1/example1-env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/http/request.py in get_host, line 109
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python3
Python Version: 3.5.1
Python Path:    
['/usr/lib64/python3.5',
 '/usr/lib64/python3.5/plat-linux',
 '/usr/lib64/python3.5/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib64/python3.5/site-packages',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages',
 '/usr/lib64/python3.5/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python3.5/dist-packages',
 '/var/www/vhosts/example1/',
 '/var/www/vhosts/example1/example1-env/lib/python3.5/site-packages']
Server time:    Wed, 14 Jun 2017 20:31:27 +0000
```

As you can see, somehow Apache is trying to use the virtual environment of `example1.com` when it serves `example2.com`. How could I correct that? Each one should be served with its own virtualenv.

Here is the Apache configuration file:

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
        # This is name based virtual hosting. So place an appropriate server name
        #   here. Example: django.devsrv.local
        ServerName  example1.com

        WSGIDaemonProcess example1 python-home=/var/www/vhosts/example1/example1-env
        WSGIProcessGroup %{GLOBAL}

        # Insert the full path to the wsgi.py-file here
        WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/vhosts/example1/example1/wsgi.py

        <Directory /var/www/vhosts/example1/>
            Require all granted
        </Directory>

        Alias /static/ /var/www/vhosts/example1/static/

        <Directory /var/www/vhosts/example1/static/>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
        </Directory>

        Alias /media/ /var/www/vhosts/example1/media/
        <Directory /var/www/vhosts/example1/media/>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
        </Directory>

    </VirtualHost>

    <VirtualHost *:80>
        # This is name based virtual hosting. So place an appropriate server name
        #   here. Example: django.devsrv.local
        ServerName  example2.com
        WSGIDaemonProcess example2 python-home=/var/www/vhosts/example2/example2-env
        WSGIProcessGroup %{GLOBAL}

        # Insert the full path to the wsgi.py-file here
        WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/vhosts/example2/example2/wsgi.py

        <Directory /var/www/vhosts/example2/>
            Require all granted
        </Directory>

        Alias /static/ /var/www/vhosts/example2/static/

        <Directory /var/www/vhosts/example2/static/>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
        </Directory>

        Alias /media/ /var/www/vhosts/example2/media/
        <Directory /var/www/vhosts/example2/media/>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
        </Directory>
  </VirtualHost>
```

**Edit:**
Having read some suggestions in the comments, I have come to this. This still does not work.

```
ServerName  example1.com

WSGIDaemonProcess example1 display-name=%{GROUP} python-path=/var/www/vhosts/example1/ python-home=/var/www/vhosts/example1/example1-env/
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
WSGIProcessGroup example1

# Insert the full path to the wsgi.py-file here
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/vhosts/example1/example1/wsgi.py process-group=example1
```

...

```
ServerName  example2.com

WSGIDaemonProcess example2 display-name=%{GROUP} python-home=/var/www/vhosts/example2/example2-env/ python-path=/var/www/vhosts/example2/
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
WSGIProcessGroup example2

# Insert the full path to the wsgi.py-file here
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/vhosts/example2/example2/wsgi.py process-group=example2
```

Comment: This error has nothing to do with virtual environment. You need to add example2.com to allowed hosts in your settings.py.

Comment: You are missing the point. That will not solve it as the error comes from example1 env Python

Comment: You are setting ``WSGIProcessGroup`` wrongly. It should be the name of the daemon process group for the virtual host, not ``%{GLOBAL}``. You probably meant ``WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}``, which is recommended, but you still need the ``WSGIProcessGroup`` as well. Read http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2012/10/requests-running-in-wrong-django.html

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton If I understand correctly, can I set `WSGIApplicationGroup  %{GLOBAL}` and then give `WSGIPRocessGroup` arbitrary names of my choosing?

Comment: I have made some edits to show what I have tried (amongst other things). Still not able to get it working.

Comment: Are each of those latter examples still inside of separate ``VirtualHost`` definitions? They need to be.

Comment: Yes. I have figured out what the problem was. I am about to post an answer describing it. Would be curious to hear your opinion on the cause.

Answer (score 1):

The following configuration worked for me. In short, it serves two different Django applications at `example1.com` and `example2.com` using their respective virtual environments.

As you can see, inserting the `ServerAlias` **AND** `ServerName` made all the difference, alongside a couple of other corrections by suggested by the community.

Apache configuration:

```
<IfModule !wsgi_module>
LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so
</IfModule>

<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName  www.example1.com
    ServerAlias example1.com

    WSGIDaemonProcess example1 display-name=%{GROUP} python-path=/var/www/vhosts/example1/ python-home=/var/www/vhosts/example1/example1-env/
    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
    WSGIProcessGroup example1


    # Insert the full path to the wsgi.py-file here
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/vhosts/example1/example1/wsgi.py process-group=example1

    <Directory /var/www/vhosts/example1/>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    Alias /static/ /var/www/vhosts/example1/static/

    <Directory /var/www/vhosts/example1/static/>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
    </Directory>

    Alias /media/ /var/www/vhosts/example1/media/
    <Directory /var/www/vhosts/example1/media/>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName  www.example2.com
    ServerAlias example2.com

    WSGIDaemonProcess example2 display-name=%{GROUP} python-home=/var/www/vhosts/example2/example2-env/ python-path=/var/www/vhosts/example2/
    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
    WSGIProcessGroup example2

    # Insert the full path to the wsgi.py-file here
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/vhosts/example2/example2/wsgi.py process-group=example2

    <Directory /var/www/vhosts/example2/>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    Alias /static/ /var/www/vhosts/example2/static/

    <Directory /var/www/vhosts/example2/static/>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
    </Directory>

    Alias /media/ /var/www/vhosts/example2/media/
    <Directory /var/www/vhosts/example2/media/>

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: You don't need ``ServerAlias`` for virtual hosts to work. You only need the ``ServerAlias`` if you genuinely also need it to be visiting via host name without ``www``. The ``WSGIProcessGroup`` is redundant as you have ``process-group`` option to ``WSGIScriptAlias``. You could have use ``application-group`` option to ``WSGIScriptAlias`` to eliminate ``WSGIApplicationGroup`` as well, although do be aware that using both those options to ``WSGIScriptAlias`` will enable preloading of the WSGI script on process startup.